# can i add a listbox in GWT celltable

Tags: gwt

is it possible to add a listbox inside a GWT CellTable

Have to make some thing like in the attached Image

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at this,
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it by adding SelectionCell to the CellTable.

```
final Category[] categories = ContactDatabase.get().queryCategories();
    List<String> categoryNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Category category : categories) {
      categoryNames.add(category.getDisplayName());
    }
    SelectionCell categoryCell = new SelectionCell(categoryNames);
    Column<ContactInfo, String> categoryColumn = new Column<ContactInfo, String>(
        categoryCell) {
      @Override
      public String getValue(ContactInfo object) {
        return object.getCategory().getDisplayName();
      }
    };
    cellTable.addColumn(categoryColumn, constants.cwCellTableColumnCategory());
    categoryColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<ContactInfo, String>() {
      public void update(int index, ContactInfo object, String value) {
        for (Category category : categories) {
          if (category.getDisplayName().equals(value)) {
            object.setCategory(category);
          }
        }
        ContactDatabase.get().refreshDisplays();
      }
    });
    cellTable.setColumnWidth(categoryColumn, 130, Unit.PX);
```